PowerBI DAX - Using the result of SELECTEDVALUE() in the FILTER() Function
I have the following code to create a new Table in PowerBI based on a condition:

VAR Auswahl = SELECTEDVALUE('Y-Achse-Langzeit'[Parameter])

VAR Tabelle = ADDCOLUMNS(
    'Daten Langzeitanalyse',
    "Prüfungstyp_NIO",
    SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        'Daten Langzeitanalyse'[AVO_STATUS_DIP_INNENR] = "NIO", "Innenraum_Langzeit",
        'Daten Langzeitanalyse'[AVO_STATUS_DIP_GETRIEBE] = "NIO", "Getriebeöl_Langzeit",
        'Daten Langzeitanalyse'[AVO_STATUS_DIP_KK1] = "NIO", "KK1_Langzeit",
        'Daten Langzeitanalyse'[AVO_STATUS_DIP_KK2] = "NIO", "KK2_Langzeit",
        "unbekannt"
    )
)

VAR Tabelle_02 = FILTER(Tabelle, [Prüfungstyp_NIO] = Auswahl)

RETURN Tabelle_02

The line:
SELECTEDVALUE('Y-Achse-Langzeit'[Parameter])
comes from a field-parameter, which returns either "Innenraum_Langzeit", "Getriebeöl_Langzeit", "KK1_Langzeit" or "KK2_Langzeit".
Now, for some reason, the statement
VAR Tabelle_02 = FILTER(Tabelle, [Prüfungstyp_NIO] = "Innenraum_Langzeit")
always returns an empty Table which does not make any sense for me, because if i put in the result of the SELECTEDVALUE Function manually for example
VAR Tabelle_02 = FILTER(Tabelle, [Prüfungstyp_NIO] = "Innenraum_Langzeit")
Tabelle_02 contains the desired result, but not "dynamically" how I need it.
The general reason why I need this is to avoid having to change the status ("NIO") via another slicer when selecting a button.
I tried to force the slicer output into a string-type but I dont't get a type error or anything.

You are trying to build  a calculated table. They are always static and can not respond to selections.
